# extract 40 mm cube from 3d volume data

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, scipy, scikit-image, pydicom

I have created a 3d numpy array of data (shape: 133 x 512 x 512) from dicom format. Given a center point of a nodule location, how would i extract a 3d volume of size 40mm x 40mm x 40mm. I am not sure how would the pixel to mm conversion happens? I have attached the data here. The location of nodule is (317, 363, 89) which is (x,y,z) where z denotes the number of slice. So for this example, the nodule is on slice 89.
Here is the [sample data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UOqdW6GClZ70xzetOPO1oJl3QdTa9X4X/view?usp=sharing). It is in nrrd format. In the dicom header information, the slice thickness was given 2.5 and pixel spacing as ['0.703125', '0.703125'].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the NumPy array coordinates are reversed to (z, y, x) aka (plane, row, column), see [this scikit-image documentation](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/user_guide/numpy_images.html#coordinate-conventions) for more details on this. Additionally, let's take the voxel spacing to be equal to [2.5, 0.703125, 0.703125], though I couldn't find this information with pynrrd. But, visualising it, I these measurements looked right. The units of this are mm/pixel.

Now, you want to convert 40mm, or rather half that, 20mm, to pixels. You do this by *dividing* by the mm/pixel, so you get a box size of:

```py
>>> 20 / np.array([2.5, 0.703125, 0.703125])
array([ 8.        , 28.44444444, 28.44444444])
```

That means that the top of the box should be at:

```py
>>> np.array([89, 363, 317]) - [8, 28, 28]
array([ 81, 335, 289])
```

and the bottom at:

```py
>>> np.array([89, 363, 317]) + [8, 29, 29]
array([ 97, 392, 346])
```

(I've made it 29 on the other side to get a centre pixel and also because 28.4 * 2 approximates to 57, not 56.)

So, to get your box, you would do:

```py
>>> box40mm = data[81:97, 335:392, 289:346]
```

See the [NumPy indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html) documentation for more details about NumPy indexing.

To put it all together in a function, which assumes all the inputs are NumPy arrays:

```py
def get_box(data, centre_pixel, box_size, pixel_spacing):
    box_size_pixels = box_size / pixel_spacing
    box_size_left = np.round(box_size_pixels / 2).astype(int)
    box_size_right = np.round(box_size_pixels - box_size_left).astype(int)
    starts = centre_pixel - box_size_left
    ends = centre_pixel + box_size_right
    slices = tuple(
        slice(start, end)
        for start, end in zip(starts, ends)
    )
    return data[slices]
```

Note that this code does *not* account for hitting the boundaries of the volume.

Comment: Thanks @Juan, You are right about the image dimensions being (slice, row, col), I  mistyped in the question. Could you please explain why do you divide 20 with the voxel spacing ? And does 1mm = 1 px in this case ?

Comment: no, 1mm does not equal 1px. The pixel spacing tells you exactly what 1px is: 2.5mm along the slice axis and 0.7mm along the xy axes. Spacing is in units of mm/pixel. To remember whether you should divide or multiply you use dimensional analysis, see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_analysis , https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra/x2f8bb11595b61c86:working-units/x2f8bb11595b61c86:rate-conversion/v/dimensional-analysis-units-algebraically , or https://cel.archives-ouvertes.fr/cel-01380149v3/document